# Google Maps distance matrix working with JSON and PHP and pulling data out of JSON

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I need to pull the data out of the json file that I get back from google distance matrix.

This is what I get from google

```
stdClass Object
(
    [destination_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10 Hawkins St, Cooma NSW 2630, Australia
        )
    [origin_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30 Bent St, Cooma NSW 2630, Australia
        )
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [elements] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [distance] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [text] => 2.1 km
                                            [value] => 2142
                                        )
                                    [duration] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [text] => 5 mins
                                            [value] => 315
                                        )
                                    [status] => OK
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [status] => OK
)
```

I need to get the distance text and value and the duration text and value.

I have been trying for hours and searching the web but I cant find anything about doing it with this format, multiple arrays and stdclass objects

Would love some help on this one please, It will also help with other projects with google

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Google example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_parsing_the_results). You could copy&paste it and adjust it for PHP.